# Sign in to OneDrive without typing user informations

Tags: c#, windows-7, client, onedrive, live-sdk

I need help to obtain an authorize code, is there any way to get one without accepting anything or any window that pops up. I need this for my service as an automated process.
I tried like a thousand ways but nothing works.
Please does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx), you can use a refresh token if your app has offline access in its scope.

If offline access is set, when you retrieve your authentication token normally, you'll also get a refresh token. When the normal token expires, you can request a new one similarly to the first token, replacing the `code` query parameter with the `refresh_token` parameter.

To be clear, the process looks like this [as per the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx):

- Send your user to your web service
- Direct them to the OneDrive authorise page with the correct parameters (make sure offline access is in the scope)
- Wait for them to be redirected back to your app with the authorisation code
- Exchange the authorisation code with OneDrive (using the `oauth20_token.srf` endpoint) to receive a set of tokens (one of these will be refresh)
- Wait for the `access_token` you received to expire
- Exchange the `refresh_token` you received for a new access token as per the "Getting a new access token or refresh token" section of [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with authentication token you mean the token I get when I create a LiveConnectSession via an authorize code?
So this means after I received my authorize code once, and then do the same request, but change my parameter to refresh_token ?
But this parameter is the one I receive, but i want to sign in with this.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, and will this cause me to sign in? Or does it happen in the background? 
Thank you!

Comment: The initial authorization (where you send the user to the webpage) requires the user to manually log in but getting auth tokens with a refresh token can be done without any further action on the user's part, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, so without initial authorization there are no tokens?

Comment: No, that would mean nonexistent security which is obviously incredibly undesirable.

Comment: Yeah, but for what do I have a refresh token, when i have to login for getting the tokens anyway?
If the tokens are not for an easier sign in, for what are they?

Comment: The refresh tokens mean you only do the initial authorization ONCE. It means your user doesn't have to log in every time your app does something.

Comment: So if I log in today, do something and then the next day i want to do something again, I do not have to log in?

Comment: No, not if you use the refresh token on the second day.

Comment: Ok thank you so far, so there will no window pop up where i have to accept any terms for accessing OneDrive? Because when logging in without tokens, i have to type in my account name and password, and then accept the terms.

Comment: There are two logins. One without tokens (you need to accept terms and stuff) and one with tokens (you don't need to accept terms and stuff). Every user has to do the first one once (accept terms) before you can do the second (without terms).

Comment: Aaahh this is exactly what I wanted to know, have you got an example for how to login with the tokens? This is what I always searched for how it works. :)

Comment: All in the REST API docs dude http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx :)

Comment: I can only find the example given how to sign in without tokens, means to accept terms and stuff :S
I have already gone through this document more than a dozen times even before, I think i just oversee something like a reference or something? :S

Comment: Dude, it's right in front of you. Ctrl+F for "refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN" in the docs.

Comment: Yeah but I thought I would need an authorize code to create my liveconnectclient? As response I get the tokens yes but I still have to create a session.

Comment: Ah, you're using the C# library, somehow I missed that.

You might have to serialize the client.session after the first login to disk, then deserialize it on subsequent uses of the app.

Comment: So after serializing there is only 1 thing i want to be aware of now, I now use the liveconnectclient that I make the very first time, so now I need to keep the tokens unexpired.I already request all my tokens and I already have them (also json deserialized and stuff) so how do I now overwrite my liveconnectclients tokens with the new tokens I got?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The client should keep the tokens unexpired. You just need to initialize it with the deserialized session data.

Comment: So the client does this automatically?
Yeah but there is no constructor or anything where I can use the tokens, also I cant manually use the deserialized tokens in my client, because the token properties are readonly strings.

Comment: Sometimes I also think that things only work on Windows8 ?
Because I use Windows7.